Question about differential maps between Submanifolds
What I understood about tangent maps/differential maps between submanifolds is that if we want to derive a function that is defined on a submanifold, that then the derivative of that function is equal to applying the function onto vectors in the tangent space of that submanifold.
Is my intuition correct or am I missing something? What is the difference between differential maps and "normal" multi-variable differentiation?
Thanks for any answers.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
